# Weblogic JMS server configuration: JMS module to talk to JMS Server

Tags: jms, weblogic

I am fairly to new to JMS configuration in JMS.

Here is what i am trying to do.

We have multile JVMs of our applications in a single weblogic domain.  We want to have JMS server installed on say one JVM and rest of the JVMs refer to the first JMS Server.

So, the configuration is:

JVM1: JMS Server is installed
JVM2: JMS Module installed

Now I need to configure JVM2 to talk to JMS server on JVM1.  How do i do that?

This is on weblogic 11g

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going through the basics of [WebLogic 11 JMS configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13738/overview.htm) and then taking a look into [this good guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13738/basic_config.htm) from Oracle documentation. I know there is a lot of info over there, but in the long run it is better to know what you are doing rather than just copying someone else's configurations.